# Python script in docker can't find module which can be found correctly without docker

Tags: python, docker

I have the following project tree:

```
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── modules
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── scripts_A
│   │   ├── file_1.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   └── scripts_B
│       ├── file_2.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── __pycache__
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update

RUN mkdir /modules

COPY script.py  /app/
COPY ./modules/* /app/modules/ 
RUN export PYTHONPATH=/app/

RUN dir

CMD [ "python", "script.py" ]
```

and the files content is as follows:

```
#script.py
from modules.scripts_B.file_2 import *

def hello_world():
    external_print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello_world()


#file_1.py
def my_print():
    print("Hi")


#file_2.py
from modules.scripts_A.file_1 import *

def external_print():
    my_print()
```

If I launch the `python script.py` on my pc everything is correct, but when I run the same script via docker it raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    from modules.scripts_B.file_2 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules.scripts_B'
```

Does anybody see where the bug origins from?

**UPD**
I added `__init__`, nothing has changed.
I added inits files everywhere problem is still present

Comment: Where are your `__init__.py` files?

Comment: I added it like in the tree, nothing changed

Comment: @JamesFlash still missing some files. Check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69383130/5994041).

Comment: You added one at the only place where it is not required.

Comment: Still can't launch it, added it wherever it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You are missing the `__init__.py` for each package in your python code structure. You should have something similar to this:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── modules
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── scripts_A
│   │   ├── file_1.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   └── scripts_B
│       ├── file_2.py
│       ├── __init__.py
└── script.py
```

2. In your Dockerfile, you are creating the directory "/modules" and copying the files in the wrong way. You should change your Dockerfile for this and it should work fine:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update

RUN mkdir /app/modules

COPY script.py  /app/
COPY ./modules /app/modules/ 
RUN export PYTHONPATH=/app/

RUN dir

CMD [ "python", "script.py" ]
```

Here is the problem:

`COPY ./modules/* /app/modules/`:

```
root@1be2aa295dbf:/app# ls -lah /app/modules/
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 29 20:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Sep 29 20:46 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    0 Sep 29 20:44 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   32 Sep 29 20:42 file_1.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   76 Sep 29 20:44 file_2.py
```

As you can note, when copied the files aren't structured as modules.

With `COPY ./modules /app/modules/` the files are copied into the correct sub-directory structure.

```
root@49d94b8f0941:/app# ls -lah /app/modules/
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Sep 29 20:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Sep 29 20:49 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    0 Sep 29 20:44 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  146 Sep 29 20:44 __init__.pyc
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 29 20:45 scripts_A
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 29 20:45 scripts_B
```

Comment: That `COPY` was actually fine, he was copying by a wildcard `*` into an already existing folder ending with a `/`. `ADD` is unnecessary.

Comment: Copy pasting your dockerfile solved the problem thanks a lot

Comment: Could your point out what exactly was wrong?

Comment: Hey @PeterBadida. Did you try with `COPY ./modules /app/modules/`?

Comment: @EmidioNeto OP has: `COPY ./modules/* /app/modules/ `

Comment: @PeterBadida I will update my answer with what exactly was wrong. Generally speaking, when you use `COPY ./modules/* /app/modules/` the files aren't copied as modules. You need to remove the wildcard.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the problem was in `COPY ./modules/* /app/modules/`. It launches even if I use just :
`RUN mkdir /modules` and omit the `RUN export PYTHONPATH=/app/`

Comment: @EmidioNeto Ah, I see what you've meant! So I was wrong, apparently there's a difference between a normal shell `cp -r folder/* dest/` vs `COPY folder/* dest/`. Have a +1, nice catch.

Comment: You can use `RUN rsync -r from_a to_b` as an alternative e.g. when looking for filtering

Comment: The `/` was the hidden gem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Module is any Python file and a package is a folder with (at least) `__init__.py` file. You are missing those in the folder, thus no module for you when importing. Add them to the image.

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages. This prevents directories with a common name, such as string, unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later. ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html))

```
...
├── modules
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── scripts_A
│   │   ├── __init__.py
...
│   └── scripts_B
│   │   ├── __init__.py
...
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:alpine
RUN mkdir modules && mkdir modules/package_1 && \
    echo 'print("Hello")' > modules/package_1/__init__.py && \
    echo 'from modules.package_1 import *' > script.py
RUN python script.py
```

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM python:alpine
 ---> 03c59395ddea
Step 2/3 : RUN mkdir modules && mkdir modules/package_1 &&     echo 'print("Hello")' > modules/package_1/__init__.py &&     echo 'from modules.package_1 import *' > script.py
 ---> Running in 99e2f69bbe0c
Removing intermediate container 99e2f69bbe0c
 ---> 82ae26cd9103
Step 3/3 : RUN python script.py
 ---> Running in c8b9bc76403b
Hello
Removing intermediate container c8b9bc76403b
 ---> 393bafc59987
Successfully built 393bafc59987
```

Comment: I did like this, I have the same problem again

Comment: @JamesFlash Check your `Dockerfile` again, I've added an example in a simple Python image, works just fine.

Comment: it's useful thanks